# How to implement Await Task, for faster Web Scrape. How to make my code faster?

Tags: .net, vb.net, asynchronous, async-await

This is a unix timestamp based data, which needs to be scraped.
Files in server can be 1542688763.png or 1542688763.jpg
so my system decrement a given unix timestamp, one by one and check if the file exists.
A web developer made the same thing and his is vry fast. He said me, that due to improper usage of IO bound and CPU bound process, and improper requst and await code, my program is slower. Can anyone help?

```
Imports System.Net.Http
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading



Public Class Form1
    Dim VarHoldingUnix As Double
    Dim KotafOund As Integer
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        VarHoldingUnix = ToUnix(Date.Now)
        TextBox1.Text = VarHoldingUnix
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim DRON As Date
        DRON = FromUnix(VarHoldingUnix, 0)
        MsgBox(DRON)
        MsgBox(DateAndTime.Day(DRON))
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
        Dim ABCD As Task


        While Not KotafOund = TextBox3.Text
            ToolStripLabel1.Text = FromUnix(VarHoldingUnix, 0)
            Application.DoEvents()
            ABCD = MakeRequests(300)
        End While

        MsgBox("END")
        End

    End Sub

    Async Function MakeRequests(noS2find As Integer) As Task

        Dim tasks As List(Of Task(Of Boolean)) = New List(Of Task(Of Boolean))
        Dim tasks2 As List(Of Task(Of Boolean)) = New List(Of Task(Of Boolean))
        Dim itemsF As Integer = noS2find

        Dim DRON As Date
        Dim DronDate As String

        Dim MyYear, MyMonth As String

        DRON = FromUnix(VarHoldingUnix, 0)

       

        For i = 1 To itemsF
            i = i + 1
            DRON = FromUnix(VarHoldingUnix, 0)
            'DronDate = (DateAndTime.Day(DRON))

            
            Dim MYURLJPG As String = "https://www.secru.com/img/" & VarHoldingUnix & ".png"
            tasks.Add(CheckPageExists1(MYURLJPG))
            'await Task.Run(() => CheckPageExists1(MYURLJPG));
            Dim MYURLPNG As String = "https://www.secru.com/img/" & VarHoldingUnix & ".jpg"
            tasks2.Add(CheckPageExists2(MYURLPNG))
            'await Task.Run(() => CheckPageExists2(MYURLPNG))

            VarHoldingUnix = VarHoldingUnix - 1
        Next

        While tasks.Select(Function(x) x.Result).Count < tasks.Count
            Thread.Sleep(100)
        End While

        While tasks2.Select(Function(x) x.Result).Count < tasks2.Count
            Thread.Sleep(100)
        End While

        

    End Function

    Private Async Function CheckPageExists1(ByVal url As String) As Task(Of Boolean)

       
        Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
        request.Method = "HEAD"
        'Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse
        request.Timeout = 5

        Dim Result As Boolean

        Try
            Using response As HttpWebResponse = Await request.GetResponseAsync.ConfigureAwait(False)
                Using responseReader As New IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)

                    Dim actualResponse As String = Await responseReader.ReadToEndAsync
                    Result = True
                    KotafOund = KotafOund + 1
                    Process.Start(url)
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            'IMAGE DOES NOT EXITS
            Result = False
        End Try

        Return Result

    End Function
    Private Async Function CheckPageExists2(ByVal url As String) As Task(Of Boolean)



        Dim request As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.WebRequest.Create(url)
        'Dim response As Net.HttpWebResponse
        request.Method = "HEAD"
        request.Timeout = 5

        Dim Result As Boolean

        Try
            Using response As HttpWebResponse = Await request.GetResponseAsync.ConfigureAwait(False)
                Using responseReader As New IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream)

                    Dim actualResponse As String = Await responseReader.ReadToEndAsync
                    Result = True
                    KotafOund = KotafOund + 1
                    Process.Start(url)
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            'IMAGE DOES NOT EXITS
            Result = False
        End Try

        Return Result

    End Function

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
        VarHoldingUnix = TextBox1.Text

        MsgBox("Confirmed New UNIX-VARIABLE " & VarHoldingUnix)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I think inside Async Function MakeRequests I have to use this code

```
While tasks.Select(Function(x) x.Result).Count < tasks.Count
   Await Task.Delay(100)
End While
```

instead of

```
While tasks.Select(Function(x) x.Result).Count < tasks.Count
   Thread.Sleep(100)
End While
```

but i am not getting a perfect balance of the no of milliseconds i set within wait (100) now, and

```
ABCD = MakeRequests(300)
```

can be 200 or may be 2000.

I dont know....you guys are better knowledgeable

Comment: What's that `ToUnix` and `FromUnix`?

Comment: send a date.now to ToUnix() to convert it into UNIX time stamp....and viceversa

Comment: date to unix timestamp conversion function....and viceversa....this is a global function declared by me

Comment: Any particular reason for not using `DateTimeOffset`'s functions?

Comment: yes....because the files are stored by the unixtimestamp name. Ex 21nov2018 in unix may be 123456765, files kept in the server i am scrapping are www.secru.com/images/123456765.jpg  The software takes a given date, uses this function to convert it into unix time stamp, and then in loop sends request to server to check if the file is there....and then increases the unixtimestaamp value everytime by 1..and then chk again for the file.

Comment: Data time offset? Forget date time....Think I want to fire www.website.com/1.jpg ....2,3......Till 5000 and check how many really file exists out of 5000 urls I fired. What is the fastest way to do so?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this?

```
Private Async Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click

    While Not KotafOund = TextBox3.Text
        ToolStripLabel1.Text = FromUnix(VarHoldingUnix, 0)
        Await MakeRequests(300)
    End While

    MsgBox("END")
    End

End Sub
```